# Formatting date data in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, data-science

I would be really grateful for an advice. I had an exercise like it's written bellow:

> The first column (index 0) contains year values as four digit numbers
>   in the format YYYY (2016, since all trips in our data set are from
>   2016). Use assignment to change these values to the YY format (16) in
>   the test_array ndarray.

I used a code to solve it:

```
test_array[:,0] = test_array[:,0]%100
```

But I'm sure it has to be more universal and smart way to get the same results with datetime or smth else. But I cant find it. I tried different variations of this code, but I dont get whats wrong:

```
dt.datetime.strptime(str(test_array[:,0]), "%Y")
test_array[:,0] = dt.datetime.strftime("%y")
```

Could you help me with this, please?

Thank you

Comment: In case you use pandas for dataframe creation/load, you can simply say colname.year.  you can then manipulate to get only last two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to carry out the conversion of year from YYYY format to YY format would require intermediate `datetime` value on which operations such as `strftime` can be carried out in following manner:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: pd.datetime(x, 1, 1).strftime('%y'))
```

Here to obtain the `datetime` values we needed 3 args: year, month and date, out of which we had year and the values for rest were assumed to be 1 as default.